# Can leftover shmurah matzot from one year be used the following year?

Tags: passover, matzah, gebrochts

I had this discussion with a fellow shul member.

He has a box of shmurah matzot that he left in the closet from last year. When he opened it up, recently he noticed that they were stale. He says that since they got moist, they became chametz and cannot be used. He further pointed out that since all matzah boxes stamp the year it was made, this means that one can **never** use matzot from one year to the next.

My thinking - as long as the matzot never touched chametx, why would there be any problem using them. One of my friedns bought cases of matzot after Pesach was over because the prices had dropped significantly. The boxes were never opened, and on Pesach she had 1 year matzot. Some were a bit moist, so she put them in the oven for a few minutes and they were crisp and fine.

As for my friends concern about it being moist, I don't see how this is different than the concern with gebrokts, and then, the matzot are completely soaked in the liquid. Yet, many people eat gebrokts!

Who is correct, here?

Comment: Moisture would only ever be a problem if you hold of gebrokhts...

Comment: @IsaacKotlicky - Yes. I think I implied that in my last paragraph.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[From the Star-K](http://www.star-k.org/kashrus/kk-passover-matzoh.htm):

> Matzos left over from previous years that were stored in places free of chometz may be used. TIP: If your oven has been kashered for Pesach, simply put them in the oven for a few minutes so the matzos will regain their crispness.

Comment: Thanks. If you can link, even better. Looks like I win, again :-)

Answer (score 3):

[Bais Yitzchok 2:44](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=71&pgnum=100) discusses using Matza from the previous year. He mentions Tosefta Pesachim - end of Chapter 2 which says one may use Matza from a previous year so long it was made for Pesach. The Yerushalmi in Pesachim 2:4 indicates that it is a matter of dispute, however the Yerushalmi clearly indicates that is when it was not made for Pesach. He goes on to say that one has to be certain there is no infestation prior to eating it.

Comment: The discussion in Bais Yitzchok is regarding using the matzah for the mitzvah of matzah at the seder.