# Is old matza kosher for Pesach?

Tags: halacha, passover, time, chametz-leaven, matzah

Someone recently made the claim to me that matza from a previous year was considered chametz / may not be used on the subsequent Pesach. (And as such, they plan on throwing out the matza from last year prior to Pesach.) I find this claim hard to believe, and my first inclination is to think it is just the latest chumra, innovated by people who don't know what they are talking about. But I don't have the time to research this.

Is there any Rabbinic source which would demonstrate that old matza is considered chametz?

Alternatively, is there any Rabbinic source which would demonstrate that old matza is NOT considered chametz?

This was admittedly somewhat covered in [this question / answer](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56246/can-leftover-shmurah-matzot-from-one-year-be-used-the-following-year), but Rabbinic source I mean a gemara, Shulchan Aruch, etc., where it is discussed (explicitly or implicit from the discussion), rather than an assertion on a (kashrut) website.

Comment: Pretty close, and this will be slightly helpful, but I am looking for a Rabbinic source that would convince them and not be dismissed. By Rabbinic I don't mean a website from Star-K, but something like Shulchan Aruch, or Aruch Hashulchan. I realize that this may be so obvious as to not be mentioned in sefarim...

Comment: I'm assuming the matzo was kept wrapped the entire year and therefore away from any chametz that was about

Comment: Yes.  In the original box

Comment: This isn't a latest chumra. It's the same old chumra. People only buy chicken if it says kosher lipesach. People scrub their walls. Etc. Some make sense, some don't. We shouldn't make fun. In your specific case usually most people didn't keep watch to ensure that their matzah from the previous year is chametz free, so they don't use it. Just like they don't use an open bottle of ketchup or whatnot. But Matzah for leil sedder might be even more of a reason to be scrupulous, to ensure it is shmura from chametz.

Comment: While I understand the concern for getting a better source, I have voted to close as duplicate. I think that a source from kashrut orgs. esp. a major one containing many reliable rabbanim is already a reliable source. In this specific case, I also think that the answer is somewhat obvious. What would make old matzot where no chametz touched it year round any different than leftover coffee, spices, or other "old" Pesach product. I have a box of salt from Pesach 5 years ago, that I have still been using. How are matzot different from the salt?

Comment: @DanF You don't need to argue with him about what kind of source he wants. He wants what he wants whether you want it of not. That said, the questions are the same. R Josh, if you want better/more answers there consider adding a bounty.

Comment: I came across this also wondering if there is a source for prohibiting last year's matza as I just heard someone say that they haven't heard of any such practice.